# How to change sender email based on product id in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I am trying to change the sender email for all emails related to two products in WooCommerce, but not for all the others.

I have the code below to change the sender email, but I am not sure how to make it work for only those two products (by product id or category).

```php
function change_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'admin@example.com';
} 
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'change_sender_email' );
```

Could I somehow use the filter '`woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order`'?

I know how to use that to conditionally change the recipient of the email, but I couldn't get it to work to change the sender email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use: `woocommerce_email_from_address`

```php
// Change email sender address
function my_email_from_address( $from_email, $wc_email ) {
    // Get the WC_Order object instance
    $order = $wc_email->object;

    // Get items
    $items = $order->get_items();

    // Loop through
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

        // Compare          
        if ( $product_id == 30 ) {
            $from_email = 'my.email1@stackoverflow.com';            
        } elseif ( $product_id == 32 ) {
            $from_email = 'my.email2@stackoverflow.com';
        }
    }

    return $from_email;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_from_address',  'my_email_from_address', 20, 2 );
```